# Wordpress Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function, want to disable a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've tried to make [the following page](http://dilog.com.my/dcam-part-66-examinations/examination-schedule/#), the green color (1) event from redirecting into another page. This is the code I am using, you can find it in line 184 and it is returning the error of Uncaught TypeError.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.fc-day-grid-event').click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).prop('class');
        if (id == 'fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end') {
            event.preventDefault();            
            //i want to prevent
        } else {
            //redirect
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can anyone please advise where is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it within an IIFE syntax:

```js
(function($) { //<-----get the $ alias for jQuery here
  // inside this block $ is secured to use.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fc-day-grid-event').click(function(event) {
      var id = $(this).prop('class');
      if (id == 'fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end') {
        event.preventDefault();
        //i want to prevent
      } else {
        //redirect
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery); //<----pass jQuery here
```

Comment: You could also write this as: 
jQuery(function($) { 
  $(.fc-day-grid-event').click(function(event) {
  // ....
  }
});
Which would do exactly the same thing

Comment: @Kelvin you can see OP is already doing that and still there are issues. so i suggested this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't return the error anymore. But I not sure why it didn't run the script. @Jai